# Python Print Hex variable

Tags: python, hex

I have hex variable that I want to print as hex

```
data = '\x99\x02'
print (data)
```

Result is: `™`

I want to the python to print `0x9902`

Thank you for your help

Comment: `'0x' + ''.join('{:02x}'.format(ord(char)) for char in data)`

Comment: Note that ``'\x99\x02'`` is a string. If you want to store data, use bytes as in ``b'\x99\x02'``.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one.

```
data = r'\x99\x02'

a, b = [ x for x in data.split(r'\x') if x]

d = int(a+b, base=16)
print('%#x'%d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert every char to its number - `ord(char)` - and convert every number to hex value - `'{:02x}'.format()` - and concatenate these values to string. And add string `'0x'`.

```
data = '\x99\x02'

print('0x' + ''.join('{:02x}'.format(ord(char)) for char in data))
```

---

**EDIT:**  The same but first `string` is converted to `bytes` using `encode('raw_unicode_escape')`

```
data = '\x99\x02'

print('0x' + ''.join('{:02x}'.format(code) for code in data.encode('raw_unicode_escape')))
```

and if you have already bytes then you don't have to encode()

```
data = b'\x99\x02'

print('0x' + ''.join('{:02x}'.format(code) for code in data))
```

---

**BTW:** Similar way you can convert to binary using `{:08b}`

```
data = '\x99\x02'

print(''.join('{:08b}'.format(code) for code in data.encode('raw_unicode_escape')))
```